# Loop over a 'select int' result and pass it to another procedure

Tags: oracle, loops, stored-procedures, plsql

I already have a stored procedure which works fine `procedureA(int)`. I need the rows from the select statement to be fed one-by-one into the procedureA from `procedureB`, which looks like the following:

```
create or replace procedure procedureB is
begin
  for x in (
     select CAST(n as int)
       from table1) 
  loop
    procedureA(x);
  end loop;
end;
```

I get the following error inside the loop:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'procedureA'
```

I used the CAST even if 'n' is an integer because I thought the error was because I had to CAST the select result as an int. (Used to get the same error even before using CAST).

Comment: The error is complaining about a symbol that doesn't exist in the snippet you posted.  That makes me believe that the code you posted doesn't really match the code you're using.  You are calling `procedureB` in your loop but you say that you want to call `procedureA` in your loop.  And you are referencing the pseudorecord `x` rather that the specific attribute that you need.  But none of those would cause the error you claim to be receiving.

Comment: `x` will be a record variable, not an int. So you would need to access the *actual* column value using `x.col_name` - but as you don't give an alias to the `cast` expression the name of the column is not really defined.

Comment: @JustinCave Yes, I did have to modify the code and make it general. Also the error occurred because I tried to do 'x:=x+1' to check whether I am getting an integer and accidentally posted that error message. I will post the original error message.

Comment: Thank You Justin and @a_horse_with_no_name for your replies. You are right, I was passing the pseudo record as a attribute. I gave an alias to the column name as n2 and then passed x.n2 as an argument and it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that procedureA accepts an `int` as an argument, try this:

```
create or replace procedure procedureB is
begin
  for x in (select CAST(n as int) as numb
              from table1) 
  loop
    procedureA(x.numb);
  end loop;
end procedureB;
```

`x` is a row, not an `int`, and the result of the `CAST(n as INT)` is unnamed until you give it a name (here I called it `numb` to distinguish it from the original column name of `n`).

Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

That code should work fine (assuming procedureA can handle being passed an integer). In general, you don't need to cast your column to an integer for PLSQL to loop over it. This type of for loop basically behaves just like a cursor and executes the code in the loop for each row returned by the query, regardless of the datatype.